# Load more button not working and showing all the records on the page

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a page and I am displaying the list(MAX 200 records) on my page using ajax.
I am using the below code to call the ajax and show the response on the page.
And the second script is for a button called `"Load More"`. I have to show the 20 records on the page then the user clicks on load more than displays the next 20 records.

Now, My issue is, I am getting all the records and load more button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: 'function21.php',
          method:'post',
          dataType: "json", 
          data:{action:"employeelist21"},  
          success: function(data){
   
           $('#employeelist').append(data);
          }
        })
      });

    $(document).ready(function(){
     
     var list = $("#employeelist21 li");
     var numToShow = 20;
     var button = $("#next");
     var numInList = list.length;
     //alert(numInList);
     list.hide();
     if (numInList > numToShow) {
     button.show();
     }
     list.slice(0, numToShow).show();
     
     button.click(function(){
      var showing = list.filter(":visible").length;
      list.slice(showing - 1, showing + numToShow).fadeIn();
      var nowShowing = list.filter(":visible").length;
      if (nowShowing >= numInList) {
        button.hide();
      }
     });
  });
```

**PHP**

```
function employeelist21($pdo)
{

 $query=" sql query here";

 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute();
 $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (!empty($results)) {
$data='';
 $data='<ul><li>
  <div class="box">
         <div><span>Company</span></div>
         <div><span>Industry</span></div>
          <div><span>Name</span></div>
         <div><span>Location</span></div>
         </div>
         </li>';

 foreach($results as $key){
  $data.='<li>
     <div class="box">
         <div><h4>'.$key['Industry'].'</h4></div>
         <div><p>'.$key['industry_name'].'</p></div>
         <div><p>'.$key['name'].'</p></div>
         <div><p>'.$key['city'].'</p></div>
     </div>
  </li>';
 }
 $data.='</ul><div class="text-center"><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="next" class="btn btn_red mt-5 mb-4">Load More</a></div>';
}
else{
    $data.='No records available';
}

echo json_encode($data);

}
```

Comment: You should have your ajax in a separate function like `getData(pageNumber)` and call this function on document ready once `getData(1);` then `onClick` of `loadButton` , call the ajax `getData(2)` like that. You can have a counter as well for pagination

Comment: @IndraKumarS, I think this will take lots of time to load the records on the page.

Comment: You didn't say exactly what the issue was. You're loading in 200  and showing 20 at a time, got that. Is that part working or are you showing all 200? What is the question?

Comment: @Kinglish, I have to show 20 records on the page load, and when the user clicks on the load more than display the next 20 records. I tried the above code and I am getting my all the 200 records.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would rather transfer back a list of data (not html) in json format and use that like an array, creating the HTML for it in javascript. BUT we don't always get what we want, so in this case I would assign an attribute to each set of 20 like this:

```
// at the top of your script (not in a function)
let perPage = 20, onGroup=0

// in your ajax function ...
success: function(data){
  $('#employeelist').hide();
  $('#employeelist').append(data);
  $('#employeelist box').each( function(index) {
    if (index===0) return; //header row
    $(this).data('group',Math.floor(index-1/perPage))
  });
  $('#employeelist box').hide()
  $('#employeelist box [data-group=0]').show()
  $('#employeelist').show();
}
```

Then for the button, remove this from the PHP and make it an element under the results div

```
<div class="text-center"><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="next" class="btn btn_red mt-5 mb-4">Load More</a></div>
```

Then in your script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#next").click(function(){
      $('#employeelist box [data-group='+onGroup+']').hide()
      onGroup++;
      $('#employeelist box [data-group='+onGroup+']').show()

      if ($('#employeelist box [data-group='+(onGroup+1)+']').length ===0) {
       $(this).hide();
      }
      
     });
});
```

Hard to test here, but let me know if it doesn't work